# Android Studio 2.2 preview throwing error while implementing databinding

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-databinding, android-studio-2.2

I have updated my android studio to 2.2 preview 1 and applied the specified dependencies for google and firebase as specified but still getting the following error

```
EmptyThrowable: Wrong dependency type: class com.android.tools.idea.databinding.DataBindingUtil$LightBRField


dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

Comment: exact same issue here.. did this not happen before 2.2 preview?

Comment: I got the same problem after upgraded to 2.2 preview 2.

Comment: Ignore this error in development process, There isn't any solution till now regarding this error. I think it will take time until and unless we have the stable version.

Comment: Have in mind that it is a preview build. Preview builds usually show those bugs. You can send  a report for the developers... Update to a stable version if you're developing a production app

Comment: I had this issue early this morning. Downloading the latest [canary update](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest) (AS 2.2 Preview 7 as of today) fixed it for me.

Comment: Do you use the jack compiler ? If you do, you have to define the annotation processor used by the data binding manually

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Google repository in the Android Software Development Kit (SDK). The fastest way to do it to click:

> Help> Check for updates

Answer (score 0):

Just use latest **Android Studio 3.1.3** or new if available. You will not get this error.