# Strange error of parsing with data binding with Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2, and have some troubles when I import my project, when build is finished, that's what I have (three times) :

```
Error:|', '?', '??'}
```

When I try to double click on this error, nothing happens.
BUT on Android Studio 1.5, I don't have this problem, all works well.

**EDIT**
If it can help, I have this too (maybe it's linked) :

Wrong dependency type: class com.android.tools.idea.databinding.DataBindingUtil$LightBRField

Any idea about this guys ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information on the error messages??, the later wrong dependency type problem may be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374484/android-studio-2-2-preview-throwing-error-while-implementing-databinding

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much more information on this error. Either it comes from DataBinding, or it comes from AndroidAnnotations. But I can't provide more informations about this issue. Like the link you provided, I don't have this error with Android Studio 1.5